# Gmail displaying email username instead first and last name

Tags: sendgrid, google-workspace, email-client, firebase-extensions

Instead of *FirstName* *LastName*, Gmail is displaying only the username (*hello*)
[image]

I'm using SendGrid, domain is authenticated and security set to *automatic*. As per [SendGrid's documentation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/dkim-records#automated-security-and-your-dkim-signature), DKIM and SPF records are managed automatically with this setting.

The *hello@example.com* address is setup on Google Workspace.

Wondering if anyone has any advice on how to get Gmail to display first and last name.

Comment: What is the code you are using to send the email?

Comment: I'm using the SendGrid Firebase extension: https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

I think to display a name in the place of the sender here you should set up your Firebase Extension with the `DEFAULT_FROM` setting in the format "`Firstname Lastname <address@example.com>`".

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Works perfectly - thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad the Firebase Extension is working well for you. While that one is built by the Firebase team, I've actually been working on some more. Hope they help!